# Summarise a row with one result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains the below values across multiple rows and I'm struggling to write a query that returns just one row that summarizes the table column as shown below.

Any ideas how I can get the below result?

**Status**
Normal
Normal
Normal
Critical
Normal
Warning
Normal

Result is "Critical"

**Status**
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Warning
Normal

Result is "Warning"

**Status**
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal

Result is "Normal"

**Status**
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Critical
Normal
Warning
Normal

Result is "Critical"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rownumber for this:

```
SELECT  Status
FROM    (
          SELECT   Status
          ,        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status = 'Critical' THEN 1
                                                   WHEN Status = 'Warning' THEN 2
                                                   WHEN Status = 'Normal' THEN 3
                                                   ELSE 4
                                              END) RN
          FROM     Your_Table
        ) A
WHERE   A.RN = 1
```

You May need to add a `PARTITION BY`, depending on your other requirements.